# Specify type of nested array in mongoose?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

My Schema

```
levels: {
    required: false,
    type: Array,
    'default': [[], [], [], [], []]
}
```

The problem: It's recognized as strings. But I want it to be of type number.

So a valid example for a model would be:

```
[[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8], [9,0,1], [2,3,4]]
```

So my question is: How do I specify the correct type?

I've tried `[[Number]]` which wasn't working.